# Database Handler in Realm for Android

Tags: android, realm

I am trying to implement Realm in Android. Is there a way to implement like a **Database Handler in SQLite**?  Every samples found is in UI and just under some button clicks. There is no pure implementation on seperate database file.

I have a Database Handler class as below:

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {  

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyTrain";
private static final String TABLE_ROUTE = "Route";
private static final String COLUMN_ID = "Id";
private static final String COLUMN_ROUTENAME = "RouteName";
private static final String COLUMN_REMARKS = "Remarks";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
 String CREATE_ROUTE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " 
      + TABLE_ROUTE + "("+COLUMN_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," 
      + COLUMN_ROUTENAME+" TEXT,"+COLUMN_REMARKS+" TEXT)";
 db.execSQL(CREATE_ROUTE_TABLE);
}

 @Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_ROUTE);
    onCreate(db);
}

//to insert data
public void AddRoute(int Id, String RouteName, String Remarks)
{
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_ID, Id);
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_ROUTENAME, RouteName);
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_REMARKS, Remarks);
    sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_ROUTE, COLUMN_ID, contentValues);
    sqLiteDatabase.close();
}

//Other CRUD Operation Functions lies here....
}
```

I want to make similar functions and database handler class that is dedicated to database stuffs..
So, how do i implement similar feature in Realm database..

Comment: Can you please provide more details about your use-case? Also, is this a typo? "Database Handler in SQLite"

Comment: @Emanuelez I have added some dummy functions that i am using in sqlite and want similar features in Realm. So, is it possible to do same stuffs not in UI?

Comment: Realm doesn't have a DatabaseHandler like SQLite. The schema is automatically created for you by just creating your model classes. Upgrades are handled through Migrations. If you want you can create your own class that encapsulates Realm access, but it is not a requirement.